# image sizes - force size through css, or create image to a specific size

Tags: image, css

Is it better to force an image into a specific size constraint (width and height) or to construct image to a specific dimension.  Is there a performance hit taking a large image and constrain it to a certain width/height that's smaller than the original file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only performance hit is wasted bandwidth, depending on the size of the original. Why download a huge image if it is going to be small on a page.

Comment: That, memory and processor usage on the client and browsers often do a poor job of resizing for some unfathomable reason.

Comment: It's still negligible in terms of speed. Quality is not a factor of processor or memory though, but rather the algorithm used by the browser.

Comment: Granted, he just said performance rather than quality - but it's still a consideration.  Was just adding to your list.